# Cannot set extjs bind tag dynamically with multiple bind components

Tags: button, data-binding, extjs6

I am trying to dynamically bind to a value on a button.

I previously had

```
xtype: 'button',
Text: 'my button',
Bind: {'mystring'}
```

And then in another one of my .js files I had

```
MyApp.model.ModelView.getView().getViewModel().set(receivedTag, receivedData);
```

This was setting the value correctly, but now I want to add a second bind value to my button to bind a style too so my button now is

```
xtype: 'button',
Text: 'my button',
Bind: {myTag :'{myString}', 
         Style: '{background}'}
```

Using the method I had for setting the bind tag dynamically no longer works and returns an error of

```
Cannot bind myTag on Ext.button.Button - missing setmytag method
```

Any help would be appreciated as it was working fine before i decided I wanted a second tag!

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/application_architecture/view_models_data_binding.html

You have to implement an additional setter method for myTag property, i.e. setMyTag, so that your button config should be as following:

```js
{
  xtype: 'button',
  myTag: undefined,
  text: 'my button',
  setMyTag: function(value) {
    this.myTag = value;    
  },
  bind: {
    myTag :'{myString}', 
    style: '{background}'
  }
}
```